# Tmux if-shell condition always false

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to set my `TERM` environment variable for tmux sessions in my `.tmux.conf` based on the value of `TERM` inherited from the parent shell (which is bash). Note that I have the following line in my `.tmux.conf` so that `TERM` actually gets inherited:

```
set -g update-environment '...some variables... TERM'
```

Basically, `TERM` is `xterm-256color` in the parent shell, and I detect that and set the `default-terminal` option using the following:

```
if "[[ ${TERM} =~ 256color ]]" 'set -g default-terminal screen-256color'
```

That line works in tmux 1.9a on my work PC (RHEL 6.6) and properly sets `TERM` to `screen-256color`, but on other PCs (including an Ubuntu PC at work running tmux 1.8 and my home Ubuntu PC running tmux 2.1), the 'condition' command always seems to be returning false, and so `TERM` is still `screen` inside the new tmux session.

I also tried doing `if 'true' 'set -g default-terminal screen-256color'`, and that didn't work either! (`TERM` is still `screen` inside the new tmux session).

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? And maybe offer some info as to why it works on one machine but not on the other two?

---

UPDATE:

After running `tmux` with extreme verbosity turned on (`tmux -vvvvvvvvvv`), I think I see the issue.

Looking at the `tmux` server log file (tmux-server-xxxx.log), I see the following log lines, in this order (with other lines between them, which I've omitted):

```
run job 0x55fbca2e7240: [[ xterm-256color =~ 256color ]], pid 4955
cmdq 0x55fbca2dc250: new-session (client 7)
session 0 created
job died 0x55fbca2e7240: [[ xterm-256color =~ 256color ]], pid 4955
```

So it appears as though the new session is being created *before* the shell command exits, and so the session option isn't being set until later...but it *is* being set.

To confirm this, if I detach this session, edit `.tmux.conf` to comment out the line that checks `$TERM`/sets `default-terminal`, then create a new session, that new session has `TERM = screen-256color`.

Over on the RHEL computer where the command is working as expected, these log lines are appearing in a different order:

```
run job 0x1e82ce0: [[ xterm-256color =~ 256color ]], pid 17656
job died 0x1e82ce0: [[ xterm-256color =~ 256color ]], pid 17656
cmdq 0x1e66850: new-session (client 7)
session 0 created
```

...which is as expected. And `TERM` is set appropriately to `screen-256color`.

I'm not specifying the `-b` option to the `if-shell` command, so I'm not sure why my command appears to be executing in the background on these two Ubuntu macines. I wonder if this is a possible race condition in tmux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I probably have an answer to your pre-update questions.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030702/5875021):

> note that tmux uses /bin/sh -c to execute the shell command we specify. Thus, the command must be POSIX compliant, so tests of the form [[ are not guaranteed to be portable. Modern Ubuntu and Debian systems, for example, symlink /bin/sh to dash.

That was the thing in my case. Everything works after I replaced "your" method with the following:
`if-shell "echo $TERM | grep 256color" 'set -g default-terminal screen-256color'`

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. I just tried this on a CentOS 7 machine with tmux 1.8 here at work, and I got the same race condition-like behavior as in the update above. Note too that the `[[` method _is_ working (somewhat) in the OP, just with the race condition behavior

Comment: What a pity. Could you try with your home Ubuntu PC running tmux 2.1 (that's the distro and tmux version that I have)? Note too that I didn't say it is impossible for `[[` method to work, only that it's not guaranteed to work ;)

Comment: Wow, that seems to have solved it on that system (Ubuntu 16.04, tmux 2.1). Looking at the server log, it appears that the 'race condition' like behavior is no longer being exhibited, even in the case when I use `[[`. But, as you said, the `[[` isn't guaranteed to work, and it indeed doesn't.

Comment: So it seems that the race-condition-like behavior was changed (fixed?) from tmux 1.8 to 2.1, but my bigger issue was that the CentOS and Ubuntu machines were not accepting the BASH syntax in the `if-shell` command. Thanks!

Comment: You said everything worked on your PC with tmux 1.9a and my method solved problem on our PCs with tmux 2.1, but not on your machine with tmux 1.8. Then maybe it's caused also by the version of tmux? Too old version, being more specific.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm guessing. I meant to say that in my comment; so tmux 1.8 seems to have an issue where it processes the `if-shell` condition job in the background, which apparently was fixed by or prior to 1.9a. But the bigger, perhaps more important problem, IMHO, was that I was using non-POSIX syntax, as you pointed out